# Wordpress - Load More get_categories button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i like to create a load more button.

I'm using `get_categories` to show my categories. (i've a tv show website, so i use categories to display series and the posts are from episodes. [Example](http://prntscr.com/6n7xu4))

This is my code, can help me to change the pagination to a **Load More** button?

```
<?php
  $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'cat_name',
      'hide_empty' => 1,
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'parent' => '0'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    $numOfItems = 25;
    $page = isset( $_GET['pagina'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['pagina'] ) : 1;
    $to = $page * $numOfItems;
    $current = $to - $numOfItems;
    $total = sizeof($categories);
      for ($i=$current; $i<$to; ++$i) {
        $category = $categories[$i];
       if ($category->name) { 
         echo '<a class="cover margin-ultimos" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">';
         echo '<div id="cover-home" class="gray-shadow">';
          echo '<img src="'. get_field( 'portada', 'category_'.$category->term_id ). '" alt="Portada '. get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ) . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
        if ( strlen(get_cat_name ( $category->term_id )) > 20 ) { echo '<p class="text-ultimos menor">'.substr(get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ), 0, 20).'...</p>'; } else { echo '<p class="text-ultimos menor">'.get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ).'</p>';} 
         echo '<p class="last-info">'.$category->category_count.' Episodios</p></a>';
      }
  }
    unset($category);

    echo '<div class="clr"></div>';
    echo '<div class="paginacion">';

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagina', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Anterior'),
        'next_text' => __('Siguiente <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $numOfItems),
        'current' => $page
    ));
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What currently happens when you click on the post? Can you provide your site url?

Comment: Posts are episodes, and categories are a serie. Post: http://bit.ly/1ystaXy Category: http://bit.ly/1Eq2sX2 Home with pagination: http://bit.ly/1BJ8pZ3

Comment: And the Load More button should be ajaxed or not?

Comment: Yes, of course, with ajax maybe will work great. You what recommend?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Remove the current pagination, put a load more image, set event handler on click on that image, launch an ajax request with jquery on next page and grab the post items, append them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

So, this is my solution, maybe this help something.:

> **JavaScript**

```
var cvr = 1;
function caverload(){
    $('#textito').hide();
    $('#cargando').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/index.php',
            data: 'pagina='+(cvr+1),
            success: function(html){
                a = html.split('<span id="spliteado">');
                b = a[1].split('</span>');
                (b[0]==='' || b[0].length<20 || b[0]===null)? $('#nohaymas').show() : $('#ultimos-episodios').append(b[0]);
                cvr = (cvr+1);
            },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#cargando').hide();
                    $('#textito').show();
                }
        });
    return false;
}
```

> **PHP**

```
<span id="spliteado">
<?php
  $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'cat_name',
      'hide_empty' => 1,
      'hierarchical' => 0,
      'parent' => '0'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    $numOfItems = 20;
    $page = isset( $_GET['pagina'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['pagina'] ) : 1;
    $to = $page * $numOfItems;
    $current = $to - $numOfItems;
    $total = sizeof($categories);
      for ($i=$current; $i<$to; ++$i) {
        $category = $categories[$i];
       if ($category->name) { 
         echo '<a class="cover margin-ultimos" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">';
         echo '<div id="cover-home" class="gray-shadow">';
          echo '<img src="'. get_field( 'portada', 'category_'.$category->term_id ). '" alt="Portada '. get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ) . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
        if ( strlen(get_cat_name ( $category->term_id )) > 20 ) { echo '<p class="text-ultimos menor">'.substr(get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ), 0, 20).'...</p>'; } else { echo '<p class="text-ultimos menor">'.get_cat_name ( $category->term_id ).'</p>';} 
         echo '<p class="last-info">'.$category->category_count.' Episodios</p></a>';
      }
  }

    echo '</span>';
    unset($category);
    echo '<div class="clr"></div>';

    echo '<div class="lalala">';
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagina', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('A'),
        'next_text' => __('S'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $numOfItems),
        'current' => $page
    ));
    echo '</div>';
?>
</div>  
<div class="clr"></div>
<div  id="caverload" class="paginacion" onclick="return caverload();">
        <a id="textito">Cargar Más Series</a>
    <div id="cargando" style="display:none">
        <a style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 117px; padding-left: 117px;">
            <img src="http://a.disquscdn.com/1427500112/img/loader.gif"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nohaymas" style="margin-top: -20px;display:none">
        <a>Eso es Todo Amigos</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I split the content, onclick button.

You can show how it work, [here](http://series.enlatino.net/)

Wherever, thanks a lot for your help to all commenters

Answer (score 3):

Your html pagination is:

```
<div class="paginacion"><span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="/?pagina=2">2</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="/?pagina=3">3</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="/?pagina=2">Siguiente <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div>
```

please change that with "Load More", maybe like this:

```
<div class="paginacion" id="loadmore">Load More</div>
```

Create event handler with jquery and use ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// count length catalog diplay first
   var start = $("#ultimos-episodios > a").size();
   var offset = start*2;
   var clone = $("#ultimos-episodios > a").eq(0).clone();

 $('#loadmore').click(function(){

   $.ajax({
    url:"linktoyourphpcategory.php", 
    dataType:"json",
    type:"post",
    data:{start_p:start,offset_p:offset},
    success:function(data) {
       clone.find('a').attr('href',data.href);
       clone.find('img').attr('src',data.src);
       clone.find('img').attr('alt',data.alt);
       clone.find('p').eq(0).text(data.title);
       clone.find('p').eq(1).text(data.episode);

       // add that
       $("#ultimos-episodios").append(clone);

       //reset clone
       clone = clone.clone();

       // update start and offset
       start = start+start;
       offset = offset+start;
    }
   });


 });
});
```

Last, in your php code, maybe like this:

```
$numOfItems = $_POST['start_p'];
$offset= $_POST['offset_p'];

$args = array(
      'orderby' => 'cat_name',
      'hide_empty' => 1,
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'parent' => '0',
      'offset' => $offset,
      'limit' => $numOfItems 
    );

$categories = get_categories($args);

$item = array();
foreach($category as $cat){
  $item[]= array("href" => $cat->'yourlink',
  "src" => $cat->'yoursourcefile',
  "alt" => $cat->'yourtitlealtcategory',
  "title" => $cat->'yourtitlecategory',
  "episode" => $cat->'yourepisode');
}

echo json_encode($item);
```

Comment: Hi @Wahyu Kodar, thanks for ur reply. In the `foreach` i must include the markup html, like: `"episode" => $cat->'<p class="last-info">'.$cat->category_count.' Episodios</p></a>'` or only the function?

Comment: $cat->episodes, it's mean $cat is result object query and episodes is field name in your table database..

Comment: This script clone the data and put this over the content, no? In `index.php` i should include the same php of `linktoyourphpcategory.php`? I try to make this work, but when i click on button `#loadmore` nothing happen

Comment: ensure your path url ajax.. and ensure your name convension in your php code and database is match..

Comment: Well, i ensure that, but this still not working. I'm test with a simple ajax and simple php file, the path are correct, and display content, but, when i use the ajax that you write, this return anything. I don't know what to do. Thanks a lot, i will try again at midnight. Regards.